# when using .load() I get all the divs from the external page but I only want one div to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have this script:

```
    $(".circwrapper").on("click", '.menuwrapper', function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var text =  $this.find('.title').text();
        // alert(text);
        $('.infodisplayed').load('display.html' + '#' + text + '> *')
    })
```

the `.menuwrapper`'s are on the same page as `.infodisplayed`. When the user clicks on one of the menu wrapper it should get text that is in a child(.title) of the `.menuwrapper`(that works, it gets the text) that was clicked so it could be used to match up with a name of the ID of a div in display.html. because I would like that matching div to display in the `.infodisplayed` div. The problem is that all the divs are being displayed in the `.infodisplayed` div. I just want the div that matches the text to be displayed.

maybe you could see the problem in my load function or other parts of the script and let me know of a solution. If you need the jsfiddle it will take me like 10 minutes.

I know that `'> *'` at the end of the load function is not necessary but that should not be the problem. I put that there to see if it will help

Thank you guys.

[Jsfiddle that Shows the index page](http://jsfiddle.net/5pz6P/)

below is the display.html page

```
<div id= "Chicken">
    <!-- <h2>Chicken</h2> -->
    <h1>Chicken </h1>



</div>
<div id= "Sidedishes">
    <h1>Side dishes</h1>


</div>

<div id= "Salads">
    <h1>Salads</h1>

</div>

<div id= "Soup">
    <h1>Soups</h1>

</div>

<div id= "Fish">
    <h1>fish</h1>

</div>

<div id= "Deli">
    <h1>Deli</h1>
            <table>

        </table>
</div>

<div id= "Liver">
    <h1>liver</h1>

</div>

<div id= "Beaf">

</div>
```

Comment: can you share a sample markup of `infodisplayed`

Comment: do you mean display.html because infodisplayed is just an empty div

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When loading a [page fragment](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments), the path and selector need to be spaced in the resulting string:

```
$('.infodisplayed').load('display.html #' + text + '> *')
//                                    ^
```

Without that space, the `#` and `text` would be treated at least in part as a [URL fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) instead:

```
'display.html' + '#' + text + '> *'
// 'display.html#...> *'
```

Comment: thanks I tried that, didnt work. I will make a jsfidle so you can help find the error. ill let you know when im done

Comment: OK I added the js fiddle and the display.html page is in the question. if you could help me get one div  in infodisplay div from display.html that would be appreciated

Comment: I found my answer thank you so much for your help. this question is closed

Comment: @user2537537 Adjusted slightly to use JSFiddle's [`/echo/html/`](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html): http://jsfiddle.net/3yzaR/1/.